# Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

Tags: android, eclipse, export

I'm exporting android application (in Eclipse) and get the following error:

```
[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced class android.security.NetworkSecurityPolicy

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics] Warning: there were 3 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)

[2016-07-31 09:21:57 - EnglishPhonics]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I'm using Google Billing service with lastest version. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: this error fixed because I'm using android sdk ver 21. I just change to ver 23.